# How can I prove that$ S = \{(x,y)\in \Bbb N^2 \mid (2-x)(2-y) < 2(4-x-y)\} $ is a subset of $T = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,1)\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove equality between the sets. I know that substituting T into S proves that T is a subset of S, however, I don't know how I can show that S is a subset of T. So far I algebraically manipulated the formula to get $xy > 4.$

Comment: Did you forget to include some restrictions? If $x=2$ then the defining property of $S$ becomes $ 0<2\times (2-y)$ which is equivalent to  $y<2$.  But the points $(2,y)$ for $y<2$ are not all in $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $S$ should be defined as

$$S=\{(x,y) \in (\mathbb{N}^+)^2: (2-x)(2-y) < 2(4-x-y) \}$$

as otherwise we'd have non-integer (and negative and zero) solutions as well.

So suppose $(x,y) \in S$ and we have the inequality holding. Then

$$4-2x-2y + xy < 8-2x - 2y$$

from which it follows that $xy < 4$ (adding $2x+2y-4$ to both sides).

As we have positive integers $x$ and $y$ it's quite clear that $x \le 3$ and $y \le 3$ but $x=3$ implies $y=1$ and vice versa. $(2,2)$ is just out, but taking one of them smaller than $2$ does work. So $(x,y)$ is in the right hand side.

Comment: +1: Skunked me! I might say "As we have *positive* integers...," but it looks optimal, otherwise!